# How to find specific Value/Table in SQL 2008 Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a specific Value in an AutoDesk Vault Database.
The Value is: TESTFB_SW and it is a property of an .tif File.

I have changed the value and logged this using the SQL Server Profiler:

```
declare @p2 dbo.t_propertyvalue
insert into @p2 values(106,N'nvarchar',N'TESTFB_SW')

declare @p3 dbo.t_value
insert into @p3 values(106)

exec AddProperties @EntityId=158488,@PropertiesTable=@p2,@pdefsToAssocToEntity=@p3,@overwriteExisting=1
```

In which Database is the table dbo.t_propertyvalue stored? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't.
`dbo.t_propertyvalue` is not an actual table that you can find in the database. It is a [User-Defined Table Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It is a type that basically is a table declaration, and can be used to create table variables without explicitly listing all the column definitions every time.
In your example type `dbo.t_propertyvalue` is used to create table variable `@p2`, which is then used as table-valued parameter in `AddProperties` procedure. 
If you want to find underlaying table that hold 'TESTFB_SW' value, you should look for it in procedure definition.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found the stored Procedure AddProperties, but where is 'dbo.t_propertyvalue' declared?

Comment: @StefanWittmann It won't be declared in sp. Procedure does accept `@p2` variable of type `dbo.t_propertyvalue` as it's second parameter named `@PropertiesTable`. So you need to track what happens to `@PropertiesTable` inside `AddProperties` proc.